# Why POSIX has not specified wdiff

Tags: posix, diff

POSIX standard has specification for `diff command`. I searched internet for `wdiff specification` but was not able to find. Kindly share the reference if there is a specification or is there any reason for not defining wdiff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no POSIX specification for `wdiff` (but of course there is a [wdiff(1) manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/manual/wdiff.html)).

The reason for POSIX not specifying `wdiff(1)` is that it

1. Is not one of the historically important Unix tools
2. Its basic functionality is scriptable
3. The POSIX stance is to standardize existing practice, not new tools